# How to set default NDK's path in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I download a specify version of NDK : ndk-r12b.

I have set NDK's path in .bash_profile :

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Hans/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export ANDROID_NDK=/Users/Hans/Library/Android/ndk/android-ndk-r12b
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_NDK
```

But, my android studio can't find my default NDK's path. I have to set NDK's path in every android project in project struct.

anyone can help me? please.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid the recent Android Studio cannot work with r12. There are delicate dependencies between the versions of NDK, Android Studio, and Gradle Plugin. If you cannot upgrade to the latest versions, your best choice would be to compile your native code with  NDK r12 from command line, and let Android Studio pack the 'prebuilt' native libraries.